Automatic payment of app subscription using apple pay
I have an app that I subscribed to using apple pay.
I wanted to know if it is possible to make the subscription amount be deducted from the user's account every month without intervention, to enable automatic payment for him.
If anyone knows an idea or source for this topic, I would appreciate it

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
